# How to get all possible arguments for a wordpress function

Tags: author, profiles

I'm trying to get all arguments for function `get_the_author_meta()` or `the_author_meta()`
because I have custom profile fields such as "parent name" and so, not only the normal arguments which is in [Function_Reference/the_author_meta](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_author_meta)

I tried php `func_get_args()` but I can't make it work

any suggestions ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are confusing function arguments with author (user) meta fields. To get all user meta fields you can use [`get_user_meta()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_user_meta) with empty `$key` parameter. For example, for user with ID 45:

```
$user_meta = get_user_meta( 45 );
```

`$user_meta` will be an array with all meta fields for the user with ID = 45.

Answer (score 1):

The user meta, including the custom ones, are saved in the `wp_usermeta` table. You can get all user properties and meta keys using [get_userdata( $userid )](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_userdata), an alias of `get_user_by( 'id' )` , which returns a WP_User object or false on failure (the user with that ID does not exist).

Furthermore, you can determine if a certain meta key or property is set for a certain user using `__isset($key)`. You can access a meta key or property using `__get($key)`;

For example, you can make a shortcode to display user properties and/or meta keys with

```
add_shortcode('get-user-property', 'get_user_property');
function get_user_property( $atts ) {
    $atts = shortcode_atts( array(
        'user' => get_current_user_id(),
        'key' => 'display_name',
    ), $atts, 'get-user-property');
    $ud = get_userdata($atts['user']);
    return $ud ? 
        ($ud->__isset($atts['key']) ?
            $ud->__get($atts['key']) :
            (isset($ud->{$atts['key']}) ? 
                $ud->{$atts['key']} : 
                '[not set]'
            )
        ) : 
        '[user does not exist]';
}
```

Now you can get any user property/meta-key using `[get-user-property user="%id%" key="%field_name%"]` anywhere you have shortcodes enabled. If the prop is not set for a user, it will return `[not set]`, or `[user does not exist]` if you got the wrong ID.

If run without any arguments, it will return the display_name of the current user.

Comment: @ Andrei Thank you very much, I'm getting `[user does not exist]` I did the shortcode plugin and in the custom theme page I add `$userID=get_current_user_id();`
`echo do_shortcode("[get-user-property user=\"$userID\" key=\"user_nicename\"]");` am I missing something?

Comment: Did some testing, updated the code. Should be good now for all props.

Comment: Btw, if you use this in page content, you don't need to wrap the shortcode in `do_shortcode()`. You only need this in php files.

Comment: That one working, I could grab data and the good thing is that it's shortcode, but again I can't get all list of arguments  :)

Comment: @ Andrei Yes exactly, I know about shortcode and plugins

Comment: To see all user properties `var_dump ( get_userdata($userid) );` in some test page. Or use adminer to test queries on `wp_usermeta` table. You need `get_user_meta($userid)` to get all the custom properties. They are only available to WP_User object through `__get()`  method.

Comment: yes I forgot var_dump even better `var_dump ( get_user_meta($userID) );`